# Unable to serve the nested css & js files via nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, nginx-location

I've read some documentation and tried and number of alternatives from previous answers on this site but cannot get nginx to serve my css & js files from my flask app.  In my code i have for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src=" ../static/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
```

and my file structure looks like this:
[image: file structure]

In my nginx config '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/src' I am able to get the html files within templates to serve ok and also able to get the 'log_big.png' file within the static folder to serve ok... but I cannot get the 3rd location entry to work and serve these nested files:

```
server {
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
location /templates {
    alias  /home/www/src/templates/;  # This works ok for html files
}
location /static/ {
    alias  /home/www/src/static/;  # This works ok for the .png file
}
location /CSS/ {
    autoindex on;
    root  /home/www/src/static/;   # This doesn't work ?
}

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
}
```

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Have you checked the `nginx-access.log` and `nginx-error.log`? I notice that you use inconsistent case, does your implementation ignore case?

Comment: You accepted request on CGI but you want pushing static files with flask/nginx/etc ? You can't handle hardware buffer twice, any read/accept command will be cleared hardware buffer.

Comment: Not only do you mix the case (`CSS` vs `css`), you include `../static/` in the JavaScript path. Remove that.

Comment: @dim, the your suggestion fixed for me by amending the pointer in the code as suggested... pretty dumb mistake but thanks :)  If you wish to add as an answer I will mark as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do you mix the case (`CSS` vs `css`), you include `../static/` in the JavaScript path. Fix the capitalization and remove the `../static/`.